# Getting frequent throttling issues in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, throttling

I am getting frequent throttling issues while fetching data from access analyzer, can I know the throttling limit using AWS SDK?

Is there any other way to know more about the throttling that AWS does?
Can we increase the limit of throttling?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon publishes a [Service endpoints and quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-service-information.html) document. For most services, this will tell you how many operations you can invoke per second before throttling.

However, Access Analyzer API calls aren't included. Nor are they shown on the [Service Quotas Console page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home#!/services).

Generally that means that the quotas are high enough that you shouldn't care. But if you're getting throttled, either you're calling *constantly* or there's an unpublished quote. And, unfortunately, the only way to discover the latter is via a Support ticket.